# How do you solve $5\sin^2(x)+8\sin x \cos x-3=0$?

Tags: trigonometry

I have tried using compound angle, sum to product, pythag identities but nothing seems to work. I tried turning it into $\sin 2x$ but then I have $\sin^2(x)$ and $\sin 2 x$ together.

Comment: $\cos(2x)=\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x=1-2\sin^2x$

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$${5\sin^2(x)\over\cos^2(x)}+{8\sin(x)\over\cos(x)}-{3\sin^2(x)+3\cos^2(x)\over \cos^2(x)}=0$$

$$2\tan^2(x)+8\tan(x)-3=0$$

Answer (score 2):

$$2(5\sin^2(x)+8\sin x \cos x-3)=5(1-\cos2x)+8\sin2x-6=-5\cos 2x+8\sin 2x-1=0.$$

This is a classical linear trigonometric equation.

$$8s=5c+1$$
$$64(1-c^2)=(5c+1)^2$$
$$c=\frac{-5\pm16\sqrt{22}}{89},s=\frac{5c+1}8.$$

Comment: Nice approach! Do you think the equation would be solved as an separable ODE, i.e, $y=\sin(x)$ and $5y^2+8yy'-3=0$?

Comment: @Mikasa: how would this make the equation easier to solve ?

Comment: It is solved as you all did!. This is just an idea. Tha's it! :)

Comment: @Mikasa: mh, I don't see what you mean.

Comment: I get $y=\sin(x)$ and then put into the equation. I thought when the equation looks like above ODE(see my fist comment) so we may find $y$ and so think of using $\sin^{-1}$

Comment: @Mikasa: hence my question: how would this make the equation easier to solve ?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it as $5\sin^2(x)+8\sin x \cos x-3(\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x)$, which gives $2 \sin^2 x + 8 \sin x \cos x - 3 \cos^2 x$, a quadratic in $\sin x$.

Using the quadratic formula, the roots of $2u^2 + 8u - 3$ are $-2 - \sqrt{11/2}$ and $-2 + \sqrt{11/2}$. Hence this is equivalent to $(u + 2 + \sqrt{11/2})(u + 2 - \sqrt{11/2}) = 0$, so the original factorises as $(\sin x + (2 + \sqrt{11/2})\cos x)(\sin x + (2 - \sqrt{11/2})\cos x) = 0$.